# When does the prediction of random effects matter?

Tags: mixed-model, random-effects-model, dirichlet-process, misspecification

In linear or generalized linear mixed effects models, random effects are incorporated to explain the within-unit correlation for repeated measures over time. In Bayesian modeling, conventional prior choice for random effects are Gaussian, which is lack of theoretical justification and is chosen only for mathematical convenience. Despite its correctness, research suggests that the fixed effects are robust to the misspecification of the distribution of random effects, i.e. the estimations of fixed effects is not much affected by the choice of prior. So the choice of normal prior seems ok as long as as the random effects are not of interest.

My question then is when is the prediction (since they are random variables not parameters) of random effects of interest?  When should we prioritize modeling them accurately? And, since random effects are latent, what methods we can use to check if our prediction is adequate?